# Error of addition of curly brackets at end of enhanced FOR loop within a method

Tags: java, brackets

```
public class ClassOne {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(av(5, 6, 7));
    }

    public static int av(int... numbers) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int x: numbers) total = total += x;
        return total / numbers.length;
    }
}
```

I am a java beginner. 
I can't understand really why it fails if you had intuitively added two curly brackets at the end of the "for loop" like this below, which accordingly to presently acquired knowledge looks the most normal and natural to do it.

```
for (int x: numbers) {
    total = total += x;
    return total / numbers.length;
}
```

You can check that now. It fails after you added the curly brackets:

```
public class ClassFour {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(av(5, 6, 7));
    }

    public static int av(int... numbers) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int x: numbers) {
            total = total += x;
            return total / numbers.length;
        }
    }
}​
```

I would be grateful if anyone could clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Not adding the brackets will only run the first line. Adding the brackets will make the return statement run after the first iteration.

Comment: Again Thanks.

This mean that:

for (int x: numbers) total = total += x; return total / numbers.length;

is equivalent to

for (int x: numbers) { total = total += x } ; return total / numbers.length;

Where the for loop deals only with the part before the semicolon (;) and forgetting what is after it.
It is clear that the value to be returned (output) have to be only one value, otherwise looping the return would output more than just one value which would be confusing and lead to an error.